# Strange interaction of bash time, set -e and false, differences of bash 3 vs. bash 4

Tags: bash, time, set, posix

Following recipe to `time` `false` under `set -e` succeeds (success in the sense that the `time` output can be seen):

```
(
set +e
time { ( set -e; false; echo no0; ); }
echo yes0 $?
)
```

But following recipes fail:

```
(
set -e
time false
echo no1
)
```

As well:

```
(
set -e
time { false; echo no2; }
echo no2
)
```

As well (surprisingly it outputs yes3 under bash3 and nothing under bash4):

```
(
set -e
time ( false; echo no3; )
echo yes3 $?
)
```

As well (not very suprising):

```
(
set +e
time { set -e; false; echo no4; }
echo no4
)
```

As well (surprise):

```
(
set +e
time ( set -e; false; echo no5; )
echo yes5 $?
)
```

And following succeeds under bash3 and does something completely different under bash4:

```
(
set -e
time { ( false; echo no7; ); echo yes6 $?; }
echo yes6 $?
)
```

Note that the "no" `echo`es are not printed, while the "yes" are output by bash3 (but not all by bash4).

If you compare this with the subshell `(...)` processing under `set -e` it looks like the `time` builtin is executed with the subshell context in the `time (...)` case.  WTF?

Tested with

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

outputs

```
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
yes0 1
yes3 1
yes5 1
yes6 1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
yes6 0
```

and

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

outputs

```
real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
yes0 1
yes5 1
```

Note that "yes3" and "yes6" cases show a huge difference in how bash3 and bash4 process `set -e`.

But the "yes5" case is confusing.  It looks like "time" somehow is processed by the subshell and not in the outer shell.

**Is this behavior enforced by POSIX, is one of the bashs buggy or is it just a `bash` special behavior?**

Thanks ;)

PS: If you are puzzled why this is not academic:  There once was a script running under `set -e` ("yes3" without `time`).  It was altered to log some timing information, the hack looks like "yes6".  But now bash4 comes around and it needes a fix again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the behaviour in bash 4 is predictable,

- `set -e` will cause you to exit the current shell if any simple command in current shell or subshell of current shell returns a non-zero exit status (for a more elaborate/accurate description, read the [Bash manual's section on `set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin))
- `set -e` takes precedence over `time`, i.e. say in **no2** case

  ```
  (
     set -e
     time false;  
  )
  ```

  You exit subshell before `time` can finish executing, hence no output from `time`.

---

With that in mind, what happens in the **yes5** case (let's call the 1st `( )` as "subshell level 1", and the 2nd `( )` as "level 2")

```
(
    set +e
    time ( set -e; false; echo no5; )
    echo yes5 $?
)
```

is when you encounter `false` which returns exit status 1, the `set -e` causes it to exit subshell level 2, this returns exit status 1 to subshell level 1. But since level 1 has `set +e`, everything runs.

---

For **yes6** case,

```
(
    set -e
    time { ( false; echo no7; ); echo yes6 $?; }
    echo yes6 $?
)
```

the `false` in subshell level 2 returns triggers `set -e`, hence the absence of output.

---

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: How do you explain that `time ( set -e; false; )` outputs nothing while `time { ( set -e; false; ) }` shows the time output, even under bash4?  What causes the `{ .. }` to make such a big difference?

Comment: Here's my speculation: I found that if the subshell exits before reaching the `)`, e.g. `time ( echo "Hello"; exit; )`, `time` won't output anything. Maybe because in a sense, the command `(` was not completely executed. Anyway, since `{ .. }` groups commands, it might make `time` anticipate a group of commands (even if the group contains a single command) such that `time` shows output even if what you had is simply `( set -e; false; )` inside the `{ .. }`. It's probably a matter of context.